# How to make route automatically go to nested route path in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a home route:

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
```

that contains a sidebar component and two nested routes:

```
function Home() {

    return <div className={"home-div"}>
        <HomeNavLinks />
            <Route path={"/home/page1"} component={Page1}/>
            <Route path={"/home/page2"} component={Page2}/>
    </div>
}

export default Home;
```

The problem is that whenever I go to only the /home route, it renders the sidebar without the main content. Is there a way to make the `/home` route always go to the `/home/Page1` component while still rendering the sidebar?

Thanks

Comment: Hey grant, can ya show us your homenavlink component too?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the switch from react-router-dom

Comment: my homenavlink is just a div with NavLinks to the pages. If you're wondering about my app component, all of my routes are wrapped in a switch component there (including the /home route)

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to Page1 component to path={"/home"}. Treat this as your page one.

Comment: but if I do this, then I can't replace what is inside the /home/page1 component with the /home/page2 component while still keeping the navbar from /home